# Thingspeak to Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, iot

So I planned to create an Android app using the Flutter plugin in Android Studio. I'm still a beginner, so I'm trying a few codes, but I'm not sure if I would be able to transmit the data from my Arduino sensors to the ThingSpeak IoT platform and then to my app. I saw answers about this, maybe on java, I think, but I haven't seen a single solution to Flutter, so if anybody knows, please tell me. I'm not asking for the code, but please do enlighten me if it's possible and, if yes, how? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the http dependency and can use the get method with the write API key or full write URL that you can get from ThingSpeak database API keys section.Return value will be the http response and you can easily get the response body , status code and other parameters.